# Binary Tree search returns no results (C++)

Tags: c++, search, binary-tree

I am working on some binary tree algorithms and need a "find node with searchindex..." function. The design for treenodes is basically

```
class TreeNode {
  int index; // some identifier
  TreeNode *left;
  TreeNode *right;
}
```

and a tree is defined by a pointer to the root-node.

My implementation for the search function is:

```
void Tree::searchNode(TreeNode * root, int nodeIndex, TreeNode *resultNode){
/* Recursive search */

  if (root->index == nodeIndex) {
            resultNode = root;
  } else {

    /*  search children if the current node is not a leaf */

    if(!root->isLeaf()) {
        this->searchNode(root->left,nodeIndex,resultNode);
        this->searchNode(root->right,nodeIndex,resultNode);
        }
  }
}
```

**Arguments:** **root* is the root-node of the tree, *nodeIndex* is the search-index and **resultNode* is the pointer to the found (or not) node in the tree.

The function does not return a reference or pointer to the found node but modifies the pointer *resultNode* so it points to the found node. The idea is to initialize resultNode with NULL, perform the search and modify it if a match occurs. Otherwise it remains NULL and I can easily check if there are search results or not.

Another class with a tree *buildingTree* as member utilizes the search-function in this way:

```
TreeNode *resultNodePtr = NULL;
this->buildingTree->searchNode(this->buildingTree->rootPtr, 
                               currentNodeIndex, resultNodePtr);

// do sth. with resultNodePtr if != NULL
```

I create **resultNodePtr* on the stack because I just need it temporarily inside the function. Is this done correctly? However: The function does not work. *resultNodePtr* is always NULL, even if the tree contains a node with the search-index. I debugged it very carefully step by step, it detects

```
(root->index == nodeIndex)
```

correctly but

```
  resultNode = root;
```

does not work (I want *resultNode* to point to the same adress *root* points to).
Debugger says *resultNode* before assignment is 0x0, *root* node is some adress, after the assignment *resultNode* remains 0x0.

Do I have to overload the operator= in this case for the class TreeNode?

I have tried it:

```
TreeNode & TreeNode::operator=(const TreeNode & oldTreeNode){
 *this = oldTreeNode;
 return *this;
 // ignore childs for now
}
```

I am not an expert but this operator= seems trivial. Does it affect the assignment of two TreeNode pointers *node1 = *node2 at all?

Maybe you can help me. Thanks for reading, appreciate your help.
If I find a solution myself I will post it here.

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Is there a reason to pass in the pointer and modify it? It seems cleaner just to use a return value, and it would avoid the problem explained in the answers below.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your issue, but usually a tree is sorted, and the search can be implemented in a MUCH faster manner.  Is there a reason that you search every node of the tree?  As it is, your class searches slower than std::find on a std::list!

Comment: Also, that operator= that you implemented is an infinite recursive loop.  It should be something like `index = oldTreeNode.index; left=(oldTreeNode.left?new TreeNode(*oldTreeNode.left):nullptr); right=(oldTreeNode.right?new TreeNode(*oldTreeNode.right):nullptr);`

Comment: And any class that has pointers that own heap allocated data should obey the rule of five: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c0x.

Comment: @mdw: Yes, a return value is better and now that I know the mistake I made I changed it back.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Thanks for your ideas and links. You can speed up my function a bit if you bracket the code in "if (resultNode == NULL)" so it cancels immediately if a node is found.

Comment: @Mark is your tree sorted?  Are the nodes in Left less/more than the nodes in right?  If so, it's possible to search log(N) instead of (N/2) nodes, for a huge speed boost.

Comment: `if(!root->isLeaf()) searchNode( (nodeIndex<root->index?root->left:root->right),nodeIndex,resultNode);`

Comment: If your tree contains 1000 nodes, the above code will check ~32.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: No, the distribution (left/right) is random. EDIT: Will check out your suggestion. :)

Comment: @Mark: Balanced trees are really hard. If you're not already doing one, don't switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you pass `resultNode` into the function as a *pointer by value*, its original value never changes. Think of `TreeNode*` as literally nothing more than a number representing a memory address; when you reassign it:

```
resultNode = root;
```

This modifies the copy that `searchNode` has, but not the original pointer in the code which invokes `searchNode`. Take this simpler example:

```
void Foo(int x)
{
    x = 100;
}

void Bar()
{
    int x = 0;
    Foo(x);
    // at this point, x is still 0
}
```

`resultNode`'s value doesn't change from `NULL` for the same reason that `x` doesn't change from `0` when the function `Bar` is invoked. To fix this issue, pass the pointer in as a pointer to a pointer, or a pointer by reference:

```
void Tree::searchNode(TreeNode* root, int nodeIndex, TreeNode*& resultNode)
{
    // same code
}
```

... or:

```
void Tree::searchNode(TreeNode* root, int nodeIndex, TreeNode** resultNodePtr)
{
    // assign to *resultNodePtr instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resultNode pointer is being passed by value, not by reference. So when the function call completes the pointer on the calling side does not receive a value.

Your algorithm looks fine :)